# Не отображаются картинки локального htm-файла

Tags: html, doc

Конвертирую doc файл в htm. Получаю сам файл fileName.htm и папку fileName.files. Если doc файл содержит картинки, они помещаются автоматически в папку fileName.files, а путь к картинке прописывается в fileName.htm

```
<v:imagedata src="fileName.files/image001.jpg" o:title="Снимок"/>
```

Однако, если открыть fileName.htm в любом браузере, то картинки там не отображаются. Есть ли какая-то возможность это исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо за такое гигантское количество ответов. Вот уже на свой 6ой вопрос я получаю столь огромную помощь. Ответ конечно же я нашёл сам.

При конвертировании из doc в html нужно выбирать пункт htm страница с фильтром. Это удалит ненужные тэги microsoft, которые загружаются некорректно, из-за чего и картинки не подгружаются.

Comment: бывает так, не надо сарказма в ответах, тут все таки ресурс про программирование, а не про пользование платными продуктами мелкомягких, плюс Вам поставил потому что не поленились дать ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: хотя если бы я увидел Ваш вопрос, я бы Вам ответил про невалидный с точки зрения html тэг..

Comment: Правильный ответ будет "Если хтмлку приходится делать прямо из ворда, то сам себе злобный буратино". А правильный комментарий к ответу - "На Руси  со времен Office 97 никто этим мракобесием не занимается". Но, боюсь, вы бы на такой ответ обиделись.